# How to show div in landscape mode with cursor sould behaves like landscape mode

Tags: html, css, cursor, transform, orientation

I want to show signature pad in landscape mode on small screens.
I did transform: `rotate(-90deg);` and it becomes in landscape mode.

But the issue is that cursor still behaves like portrait mode when I enter some on pad.

[image]

Comment: You mean you need a CSS property that changes the orientation of the cursor? I don't think something like that exists.

Comment: yes i want that... or any other solution if you think